# get to bottom of page in Chrome with Keyboard-shortcut

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to get to the bottom of a webpage by pressing `CMD`+`Keydown`. Did they remove this shortcut or is it just me?

I know this used to work not too long ago and it's not working since one of the newer versions... (currently `Version 31.0.1650.57`)

`CMD`+`Keyup` still works just fine.

Comment: had nothing to do with the chrome version, extension was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got around the problem:

An extension I was using got some automatic update, in this it used `CMD`+`Keydown` as a shortcut for the extension, which overwrote the default behavior.

The problem hereby was, that the programmer was not done, so he "seized" the shortcut, but was not using it for anything.

Now after more than 2 months, after an other automatic update, the shortcut triggered something in this extension, so I could find out what was causing the shortcut not to work.

Then I just disabled that shortcut for said extension. All working now :D